# Url Pattern from RouteTable in MVC?

Tags: model-view-controller, routes, url-pattern

I have my route collection and want to retrieve the url pattern (defined in global.asax) of a given route.

In application:

```
var route = RouteTable.Routes["UserIndex"];
```

Global.asax:

```
routes.MapRoute(
name: "UserIndex",
url: "u/{userId}"
```

In the web application I am not able to access the Url Pattern (in the route object) which were defined in global.asax. Is there another way?

Im asking this because I need to define some route patterns to be used with Knockout.js in template list.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like:

```
Route userRoute = RouteTable.Routes[UserIndex"] as Route;
string pattern = userRoute.Url;
```